# Using a class within the same file as a default parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I cannot get this to work. Here is the setup:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, cls=Bar):
    self.bar = cls()

class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

This gives me:
`NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined`

But if I were to do something like place bar in another file, and use `import Bar`, that would then work, so it is an issue of scope it seems. How do I bring Bar into scope? Thanks in advance!

Comment: put the `Bar` class behind the `Foo` class

Comment: The file is read from top to bottom, when python tries to evaluate `Bar` class, it is not yet declared.

Comment: @DrutaRuslan of course, duh! Knew it was something simple that I was just forgetting about. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the order, so `Bar` will be known when it is used in `Foo`. Note that default arguments are evaluated at function definition time, not when the function is called.

```
class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class Foo:
  def __init__(self, cls=Bar):
    self.bar = cls()  # also you might want to actually use the parameter
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that they were evaluated then! And yes there was a mistake in my example, fixed that now